# Pandas pivot gives ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a simple dataframe:

```
     category cnt customer_id
0       GIFTS   1       69683
1      LADIES   3      100526
2      LADIES   2      161139
3      LADIES   2      212455
4  HOME D?COR   1      133464
```

I am trying to pivot it by count:

```
df = df.pivot('customer_id', 'category', 'cnt')
```

But it gives the error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (15, 141016), indices imply (164611, 141016)
```

There is probably 15 categories and 164611 rows in the dataframe, but I'm not sure why this is a problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce the error with your test data.

Comment: Try assigning to a different data frame like so `pivoted = df.pivot('customer_id', 'category', 'cnt')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html) function:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='customer_id', columns='category', values='cnt')
```

And make sure the type is numeric:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=float)
```